# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined (d3 force layout)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error for the life of me (using a force layout).  It started when I switched over to reading my nodes from a json file.  If I uncomment the lines below it doesn't throw an error.  If I leave as is, I get "Cannot call method 'push' of undefined".  I'm not sure what the issue is.  Am I missing anything?

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script>

   d3.json("http://katejustin.com/autosys1.json", function(data) {

   //var nodes = {};

   //data.links.forEach(function(link) {
   //   link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
   //   link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target}); });


var width = 200,
    height = 200;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    //.nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .nodes(data.nodes)
    .links(data.links)
    .size([width, height])
    .distance(100)
    .charge(-1000)
    .start();
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: -1, isolate the issue

Comment: You can revise your original post with the "edit" button under it. The main issue is the second blob of code you posted. Way too much.

Comment: There's still too much extra stuff. The main idea of isolating the issue is to make a test file that has your issue present with the *bare minimum*. For example, if you're having troubles creating 5 drop down menus with 22 submenus, isolating the issue would only have 1 drop down with 1 submenu and minimum CSS/JS.

Comment: I took the rest of the code out, so it doesn't actually do anything, but it still breaks per my original mail unless i uncomment out those lines.

Comment: check whether `data.nodes` and `data.links` has values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you try to access the nodes by `name` in links. 
In the original implementation you access the nodes by index.

Here is a trick that I usually use in these situations, even if I am sure that something easier exists:

```
var findNode = function(id) {
    for (var i in force.nodes()) {
        if (force.nodes()[i]["name"] == id) return force.nodes()[i]
    };
    return null;
}

var pushLink = function (link) {
    //console.log(link)
    if(findNode(link.source)!= null && findNode(link.target)!= null) {        
        force.links().push ({
            "source":findNode(link.source),
            "target":findNode(link.target)
        })
    }
}

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(data.nodes)
    .size([width, height])
    .distance(100)
    .charge(-1000)
    .start();

data.links.forEach(pushLink)
```

So, the goal of these functions is to replace for each link, its source and its destination by the actual object representing the node in `force.nodes`.

You can find a working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/nrbQ4/1/
(See via the console as nothing is displayed in the visualization).

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.  Can you explain though how it's different from this?  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045  That is sourcing the nodes array directly from the JSON, which is what I was trying to do.  Or is it because the links in that JSON reference the nodes' indexes.  So in your example you are basically looking up the nodes by index and storing those in the source/target links array.  This makes sense.

Comment: Exactly. Nodes are referenced by index in link's source and target.